# Check if key is in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

**How to check if there a key in the dictionary?**

Here is my dictionary:

```
edges = {(1, 'a') : 2,
         (2, 'a') : 2,
         (2, '1') : 3,
         (3, '1') : 3}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
if edges[(1, 'a')]
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_lvzelvvmfq/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    print fsmsim("aaa111",1,edges,accepting)
  File "/tmp/vmuser_lvzelvvmfq/main.py", line 16, in fsmsim
    if edges[(1, 'a')]:
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: That code does not give that error - it is perfectly valid. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `in` operator (which is accompanied by the `not in` operator):

```
if (1, 'a') in edges:

if (1, 'a') not in edges:
```

Below is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) of Python's dictionary type, where `d` is a dictionary:

> `key in d`
>
> Return `True` if `d` has a key `key`, else `False`.
>
> `key not in d`
>
> Equivalent to `not key in d`.